# How sscanf() splits a string in C

Tags: c, string, input, formatting, scanf

So basically I have a simple string and i am trying to use `sscanf()` to split this string and store the values in appropriate variables:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int i=10,j;
    char ch = 'A',ch2;
    float a=3.14,b;
    char str[20]="10A3.140000";


    sscanf(str,"%d%c%f",&j,&ch2,&b);
    printf("%d %c %f\n",j,ch2,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Now my doubt is how exactly `sscanf` knows where to split the string. Here the value `10` goes in variable `j`. Character `A` goes in variable `ch2` and `3.140000` goes in variable `b`. How exactly sscanf is parsing this string and storing values in different variables. It is appreciable if you can explain how exactly `sscanf` works with any string. I am having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: The `'A'` is not valid as part of an integer so the conversion `"%d"` stops there, `'A'` is converted as `"%c"` and the rest as `"%f"`. You really should check the return value of `sscanf()` though: `if (sscanf(str, "%d%c%f", &j, &ch2, &b) != 3) /*error*/;`.

Comment: @pmg but won't `A` be simply stored as 65 as chars are stored by there ascii values.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the job of `"%c"`: convert a character to its numeric representation; same thing with `printf("%c\n", 65);` which converts a numeric representation to a character.

Comment: @Noshiii, if you print it with `%d` specifier you will see the 8-bit character code printed out. It is stored as such.

Comment: sorry but i still don't understand. Everything here before float will be stored as decimal in the character array. When sscanf first encounters %d it will start reading the decimals. Again how will it know the decimal value after 10 is actually a char and not part of the 10.

Comment: @Noshiii, note that if you change the type of `ch2` from `char` to `int` the results are the same, with the obvious exception of the variable size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This explanation is little over-simplified and there is more than this going on inside the `sscanf` as the source code is itself more than 3,000 lines of code.

The format specifier mentioned by you in the example is listed below with their corresponding match pattern
`%d` : `[0-9]`,`[-,+]`
`%f` : `[0-9]`,`[-,+,.]`
`%c` : `[a-z]`,`[A-Z]`, Other ASCII Characters

### Parsing

[image: string parsing]

1. First, for `%d`, it will first search for `[+,-]` signs, and if not found then it will look for `[0-9]` single digits in sequence. As soon as it sees a non-single digit (A = 65) in the string, it will end its search for `%d` and save the value of the `int` to the corresponding address passed to `sscanf`.
2. Second, for `%c`, now it will take the next format specifier passed i.e. `%c` and begin again from the location where it previously stopped. This time it just has to read a single byte from the string and save it to the corresponding address passed to `sscanf`
3. Third, for `%f`, it will first search for `[+,-]` signs, and if not found it will then look for `.` and the single digits `[0-9]`. This continues until it gets something which is not part of the `%f`, which in this case will be `\0`. And save it to the corresponding address passed to `sscanf`

Finally, once everything is completed and the string is split, it returns the total number of arguments parsed. So, it a good programming practice to compare the number of the passed argument list with the returned value.

Reference:

1. [`sscanf` source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/sscanf.c.html#34)
2. [`vfscanf` source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfscanf-internal.c.html#274)

Comment: Okay got it but here we have one more issue. See i am storing this string in a char array. So not only `A` but all the digits as well will be stored as characters here and actually there ASCII values should get stored. Am i right?  Now if that is the case how sscanf will know which one is actually a digit and which one is character, afterall we are storing the ASCII codes for all only. Can you please clear this doubt ?

Comment: That's what the format specifier is for!, We explicitly tell the program to treat it as an `int` when we pass `%d` and as a `char` when we pass `%c`.

Comment: @LocalHost Like the ASCII eq of `1` is `49` but the `sscanf` will convert it to `int` by subtracting ASCII eq of `0` from it.

Comment: Okay Yes now things are getting clear. It will again convert ASCII of 0 to int and check. Similarly for `A` but when it checks 65 doesn't constitute a digit than it will immediately stop and fill the integer at the place specified. Am i saying right ??

Comment: Okay just one more doubt. What happens when i store string with whitespaces/some other delimiter between them. Like `10 A 3.140000`. Now here string is automatically splitted into 3 different parts ? How can we understand it?

Comment: @LocalHost In `10 A 3.140000`, for first part i.e `%d` it will work as expected and we get `10`, but for `%c` we will get `  ` as the char, as a white space it a legal character. And finally, for `%f`, we will get nothing/UB because `A` is not a legal floating-point match. After which the sscanf stops early and doesn't go till `\0`.

Comment: So we need to edit our sscanf format string according to the buffer string as well. Like `"%d %c %f` will give required results. Basically sscanf is matching its format with the format of buffer string to split it? Right ?

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` *consumes* the input string according to the format specifiers you defined in the format string.

Let's analyze your format string:

```
sscanf(str,"%d%c%f",&j,&ch2,&b);
```

- `%d` parses the string searching for *decimal integers*. It means that only numeric characters in the range `0-9` are accepted. Furthermore a leading sign character is accepted (like in  number `-123`). All characters meeting this criteria are consumed
- `%c` scans *any* character, saving its ASCII value in destination variable. A single character is consumed
- `%f` parses the string searching for *floats*. Like the `%d` case all decimal numbers and sign characters are accepted, but it also accepts the `.` character interpreting it as the floating point

So, let's look again at you input string:

```
char str[20]="10A3.140000";
```

1. `scanf` starts parsing from the first char. Since there are decimal numbers it consumes them until the first non-numeric character is found (`'A'`). The integer `10` is stored in `j`.

   If the string was finished here, `scanf` would have returned 1.
2. `scanf` continues parsing from the letter `'A'`. Since we have `%c` format specifier this character is consumed and the value 65 (ASCII for `'A'`) is stored in `ch2`.

   If the string was finished here, `scanf` would have returned 2.
3. After the letter `'A'` is consumed `scanf` continues parsing from character `'3'`. The `%f` format specifier will accept all the remaining characters (because they are all valid), and the value `3.14` is stored within variable `b`.

   `scanf` now returns 3.

---

I tried to empathize the value returned by `scanf` because it is checking it that you can have some control on what's going on. In your case

```
if( sscanf(str,"%d%c%f",&j,&ch2,&b) == 3 )
{
    printf("%d %c %f\n",j,ch2,b);
}
```

would prevent those scenarios in which a malformed string would have lead to undefined behavior. To understand this scenario, consider the following string:

```
char str[20]="10AB3.140000";
```

we have two *non numeric* characters after the first integer. Then:

- `%d` would still consume the value `10`
- `%c` would still consume the letter `'A'`
- **but `%f` would not consume the following string, because the substring `"B3.140000"` can't be parsed as a float**: that leading `'B'` forces `scanf` to interrupt parsing and the value 2 would be returned.

So, without a check on the return value, the **uninitialized** variable `b` would be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful explanation but still i have a minor doubt. `%d` consumes decimal values. Okay Right but we know that char are also actually stored as there decimal equivalents. So my doubt is how `sscanf` will know whether something is actually decimal or simply a char equivalent. If you are not getting my point, I can give one example to explain .

Comment: @Noshiii 
It won't. It will consume all contiguous decimal characters putting them together to compose the destination integer. For example in the string "1053.140000"; (5 instead of A) will lead to j=1053; ch = '.'; b=40000.0;. So basically scanf is powerful but cannot read our minds ;)